# How to remove duplicate rows from mysql select queries?

Tags: mysql, select

I need to run 2 mysql select queries. The second query will produce some rows that are already present in the result of the first query. How can I remove the duplicate rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

e.g.

```
(SELECT some_columns FROM some_table WHERE some_condition)
UNION
(SELECT some_columns FROM some_table WHERE some_condition)
```

This will work with any two queries (e.g. across different tables) as long as the datatypes of the columns in the queries match.

Comment: Can I sort the result set such that the row that has repeated the most comes at the top?

Comment: You can do that, using UNION ALL, and GROUP BY

Comment: No, you won't, thats why @DanSingerman said that you should use GROUP BY. The result would look like this: 
SELECT some_columns
FROM (SELECT some_columns FROM some_table WHERE some_condition
      UNION 
      SELECT the_same_some_columns FROM other_table WHERE something) AS A
GROUP BY some_columns
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC